# How to receive --data-binary from post request in google drive app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Here is my request

```
    curl --location --request POST 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/{My Web app url}/exec' \
--header 'Content-Type:  application/octet-stream' \
--header 'fileName: MyFileName' \
--header 'mimeType: application/octet-stream' \
--data-binary '@/Location/To/My/Local/File'
```

I am trying to receive this request in my google drive app script

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.postData.contents); <---- having issue with this line
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.postData.type, "TempFile");
  var fileId = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("fileName:"+fileName + " fileId:" + fileId);
}
```

The file is binary, not image not zip, but other type of binary

What do I need to write to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At Web Apps, the string value is retrieved from the event object `e` of `doPost(e)`. In this case, when your curl command is used, I thought that the binary data might not be able to be correctly sent due to the issue of the character code. I'm worry about this.
- And, when I saw your script of Web Apps, you are trying to decode the base64 data. But the curl command is not sent the file data as the base64.
- In your script, it seems that `fileName` is not declared.
- At Web Apps, in the current stage, unfortunately, the request header cannot be retrieved at the Web Apps side. It seems that this is the current specification.

When above points are reflected to your curl command and script, those become as follows.

#### Modified curl command:

In order to send the file data as the base64 data, how about the following modified curl command?

```
curl --location 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/{My Web app url}/exec' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--data '{"file":"'"$(base64 /Location/To/My/Local/File)"'","filename":"sampleFilename"}'
```

- By this curl command, the file is converted to the base64 data and sent to Web Apps.

#### Modified Google Apps Script:

In order to use the data from above curl command, how about the following modification?

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents.replace(/\n/g, ""));
  var fileName = contents.filename;
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(contents.file);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.postData.type, fileName);
  var fileId = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("fileName:" + fileName + " fileId:" + fileId);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script of Web Apps, `fileName` is not declared. So the filename is sent with the curl command.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#samplesituations)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without base 64 anything ?

Comment: --data-raw not --data

Comment: @Lena Bru Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In the current stage, it seems that the binary data cannot be directly used for Web Apps. So, the file is sent to Web Apps as the string data. By this, the base64 data is used. The byte array can be also used. But the data is sent as the string value. When you want to directly upload the file with the binary data, Drive API can be also used. But, in this case, the access token is required to be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

Comment: Is there a limit on the length of the file in base64 format?

Comment: My file size is 29MB for each file. What is parseInt here : https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/05/10/file-transfer-for-google-drive-without-authorization/

Comment: @Lena Bru Thank you for replying. About your new question of `Is there a limit on the length of the file in base64 format?`, when the file is created using the blob with Google Apps Script, the maximum size of the blob is 50 MB. It seems that this is the current specification. When the base64 data is converted to the blob, I think that the size of base64 data might be required to be less than 50 MB. I apologize for this.

Comment: Not exactly what I am asking. I tried sending a 4byte file and it worked, but i tried converting a 29MB file and it gave me an error that the file is too long for curl base64 method. IS there a limit on this? and if so what is it ?

Comment: @Lena Bru Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `but i tried converting a 29MB file and it gave me an error that the file is too long for curl base64 method.`, can I ask you about the data size of the converted base64 data?

Comment: It would not do the conversion

Comment: @Lena Bru Now, I could replicate your situation. In that case, for example, even when the 20 MB file is uploaded, the error occurred. But, when this file is converted to the base64 data and save it as a file, the converted base64 file could be uploaded. So, in this case, I thought that the combination of curl and base64 might be the reason of the issue.

Comment: @Lena Bru When 30 MB file is tested, even when the converted base64 file is used, the error like "The JavaScript runtime has terminated unexpectedly." occurred. So, in this case, I thought that there might be the maximum size for this situation. But I'm not sure about the clear reason. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231578/discussion-between-lena-bru-and-tanaike).

Comment: can you help me please figure it out?

Comment: @Lena Bru Thank you for replying. About your additional question, I still have the information in my previous replying. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67251374/how-to-receive-data-binary-from-post-request-in-google-drive-app-script/67251864?noredirect=1#comment118875963_67251864) So, when you want to directly upload the binary file to Drive API, as a workaround, I think that Drive API can be used. This reason is due to my poor skill. I really apologize for my much poor skill. I have to study more and more. Until I could find it, I think that I have to continue to apologize.

Comment: could we talk in the chat? I want to ask you a few questions, but these short messages wont allow me to write what i need @Tanaike

Comment: @Lena Bru Thank you for replying. About `could we talk in the chat?`, unfortunately, I cannot chat by real time because of my situation. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: the chat is not in real time